# Observing immutable object via @observable

Tags: aurelia

Let's assume I have a global state class that contains a TimeFrame class which has some useful properties

```
export class StateContainer {
    public timeframe: TimeFrame;

    public setTimeframe(startTime: Date, endTime: Date) {
         // treat this.timeframe as immutable
         this.timeframe = { startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime };
    }
}

export class TimeFrame {
    public readonly startTime: Date;
    public readonly endTime: Date;
}
```

Then, I need to consume this state elsewhere, so I do so via DI and then use the `bindingEngine.propertyObserver` to get changes on the `timeframe` object as one would do.

However, I would *like* be able to do something similar to the following, if it's possible:

```
@autoinject
export class Display {
    @observable
    timeFrame: TimeFrame = this.state.timeframe;      

    constructor(private state: StateContainer) {

    }

    timeFrameChanged(newValue: TimeFrame, oldValue: TimeFrame) {
         ...
         // everytime this.state.timeFrame is changed via setTimeFrame()
         // this change handler should fire, and so should any
         // bindings from this component for this.timeFrame
    }
}
```

However, when I do the previous, I only get `timeFrameChanged(...)` notifications on the inital creation, not whenever I call `setTimeFrame()`. Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are doing something wrong, I think you are misunderstanding how the `observable` decorator and the corresponding `timeFrameChanged` method are meant to be used.

Let's take it bit by bit. Take a look at these lines:

```
@observable
timeFrame: TimeFrame = this.state.timeframe;

timeFrameChanged(newValue: TimeFrame, oldValue: TimeFrame) { ... }
```

The `observable` decorator tells Aurelia that whenever the property to which it is applied changes, execute the corresponding method. Unless otherwise configured, the corresponding method is `nameOfInvolvedProperty + "Changed"` (in this case, as you are correctly doing, `timeFrameChanged`).

However, you are never actually changing the value of that property! If you actually changed that property, it would work:

```
<button click.delegate="changeProp()">
  Change prop
</button>
```

and the VM:

```
changeProp() {
  this.timeFrame = null;
  this.timeFrame = this.state.timeframe;
}
```

Now you'd see that the handler correctly fires.

But in your code, this property is only ever assigned once, here:

```
timeFrame: TimeFrame = this.state.timeframe;
```

Remember, this is just dereferencing. In other words, this code tells the app to take the value of `this.state.timeframe`, store the **momentary** value of it in that variable and forget about `this.state.timeframe`. So it does not get updated whenever `this.state.timeframe` is updated.

As described in the [documentation](http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/binding-observable-properties#introduction), you can configure the `observable` decorator to some extent, however, *to my knowledge*, there is no way to configure it in such a way that set it up to observe nested properties (or maybe it's just me not knowing how to do that).

Even if it was possible, I think a cleaner way to deal with such situations would be to use an [event aggregator](http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/cheat-sheet#the-event-aggregator). This enables you to employ a subscription mechanism - whenever the value you are interested in changes, you publish an event and whichever component is interested in that change can subscribe to it and update itself accordingly.

A simple implementation:

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { observable } from 'aurelia-binding';
import { StateContainer } from './state-container';
import { EventAggregator, Subscription } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@autoinject
export class App {

  subscription: Subscription = null;

  constructor(private state: StateContainer, private eventAggregator: EventAggregator) {

  }

  activate() {
    this.subscription = this.eventAggregator.subscribe('state:timeframe', (e) => {
      console.log('Timeframe changed!', e);
    });
  }

  deactivate() {
    // Make sure to dispose of the subscription to avoid memory leaks.
    this.subscription.dispose();
  }

  change() {
    this.state.setTimeframe(new Date(), new Date());
  }
}
```

And `StateContainer`:

```
import { TimeFrame } from "./time-frame";
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";
import { EventAggregator } from "aurelia-event-aggregator";

@autoinject
export class StateContainer {
  public timeframe: TimeFrame = null;

  constructor(private eventAggregator: EventAggregator) {

  }

  public setTimeframe(startTime: Date, endTime: Date) {
    // treat this.timeframe as immutable
    this.timeframe = { startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime };

    this.eventAggregator.publish('state:timeframe', this.timeframe);
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: "Remember, this is just dereferencing. In other words, this code tells the app to take the value of this.state.timeframe, store the momentary value of it in that variable and forget about this.state.timeframe. So it does not get updated whenever this.state.timeframe is updated."

This helped me understand a lot, thank you.

I would like if the observable decorator had a configuration property where I could do something like:
`@observable(this.state.timeFrame) timeFrame: TimeFrame;`

But, that's okay. 

Edit: Formatting

Comment: Yeah, that would indeed be nice.

Comment: Also, I ended up using a modified Flux store for managing state, rather than the nuclear Event Aggregator. Same basic principle, smaller scope. (Although, I could create a smaller scoped event aggregator as well)